# Symfony2 How to send POST Request?

Tags: symfony

I want to access my API in my UserProvider class, but I don't find any solutions, I tried with Request object, Buzz bundle, but I didn't understood everything with it.

In fact, I use HWIOauth bundle to register users and to retrieve their skills, positions, etc... this works well, but I need to create entities that are linked with it. I can't access Doctrine in my UserProvider, so I try to access my API to create entities that I want.

Is there anybody can give me an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain clearer ?

Comment: I edit it, tell me if it's not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody search an answer, I found a class that simplify the process to create HTTP request  with cURL : https://github.com/hamstar/curl

It works now !